# VMware ESXi CentOS 6.4 kickstart installation

Tags: vmware-esxi, installation, centos6, kickstart

I was trying to do a kickstart installation for CentOS 6.4 but it always show me a warning of re-initializing the HDD as it say may contain invalid partition table or a virtual disk.
I have added below is the snapshot of the kickstart file I am trying to use

```
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet" --location=mbr --driveorder="sda"
autopart
# Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda
part /boot --fstype ext4 --size=300
part / --fstype="ext4" --grow --size=1 --asprimary
```

Even I have created partitions to try as workaround but no resort. Any thoughts how to make this warning go away.
I am trying to do this through Packer-tools for ESXI host (which has 5.5 version) running.
Below is the JSON template I am using

```
# cat base-packer.json
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "vm_name": "Centos6.5",
      "type": "vmware-iso",
      "iso_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso",
      "iso_checksum": "0d9dc37b5dd4befa1c440d2174e88a87",
      "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
      "disk_size": "20480",
      "disk_type_id": "thin",
      "http_directory": "~/packertemplatebuilding",
      "remote_host": "191.168.42.3",
      "remote_datastore": "52dfe32b-a996d262-9b46-2c4138a85a23/Centos6.5",
      "remote_username": "root",
      "remote_password": "rootpass",
      "remote_type": "esx5",
      "ssh_username": "vagrant",
      "ssh_password": "vagrant",
      "ssh_port": 22,
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "250s",
      "shutdown_command": "echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S shutdown -P now",
      "headless": "false",
      "boot_command": [
        "<tab> text ks=http://148.147.206.152:8000/ks_new.cfg<enter><wait>"
      ],
      "boot_wait": "20s",
      "vmx_data": {
        "ethernet0.virtualDev": "vmxnet3",
        "ethernet0.networkName": "VM Network",
        "ethernet0.addressType": "generated",
        "ethernet0.present": "TRUE",
        "ethernet1.virtualDev": "vmxnet3",
        "ethernet1.networkName": "VM Network 2",
        "ethernet1.addressType": "generated",
        "ethernet1.present": "TRUE",
        "ide0:0.fileName": "disk.vmdk",
        "ide0:0.present": "TRUE",
        "ide0:0.redo": "",
        "scsi0:0.present": "FALSE",
        "memsize": "2048",
        "numvcpus": "2",
        "cpuid.coresPerSocket": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
"provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "script": "ssh-commands.sh"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the snapshot of the error I am getting.
[image]

PS The image I am using is a custom spin from CentOS 6.4. But I don't think that kickstart config should have an impact on the same.

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: Its a re-initialize dialog box come when the machine boots up. Saying that its either a virtual disk. So would you like to continue as it will loose any existing data.

Comment: So you installer is running in Graphical mode as well? Can you add `text` to your kickstart? Also, please correct the `clearpart --all` line.

Comment: What is the custom spin? Also, you seem to be interchanging CentOS 6.4 and 6.5.

Comment: @ewwhte, Sorry for creating confusion. The example above have CentOS6.5 iso as due to some reason I can't specify the actual name of ISO. But as I said the ISO is spin using CentOS 6.4 base and it should not impact the kickstart installation.

Comment: If you're so confident about it you should try the same file on a standard ISO to verify.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: Nope finally I left trying it :( As I tried Centos image (from official site) it work out of box but the image we deliver didn't work and got busy with other work. So not much progress.

Answer (score 5):

If you're receiving an error message similar to the following in your EL6 kickstart, you'll need to add `zerombr` to the kickstart command set.

You should also have this instead:

```
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
```

[image]

From the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html):

> zerombr: 
>   If zerombr is specified any invalid partition
>   tables found on disks are initialized. This destroys all of the
>   contents of disks with invalid partition tables. This command is
>   required when performing an unattended installation on a system with
>   previously initialized disks.

Edit:

I just tried this on a fresh CentOS EL6.5 virtual machine running on a vSphere 5.5 platform... The following worked three times in succession without issue, including a reinstallation on the same disks:

```
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
part /boot --fstype ext4 --size=300
part /usr --fstype ext4 --size=10240 --asprimary
part / --fstype ext4 --size=20480 --asprimary
part /var --fstype ext4 --size=6144
part swap --size=8192
part /tmp --fstype ext4 --size=2048
```

Comment: Yeah, Similar error and if you see my kickstart snapshot I already have added zerombr but still same error. Even I have tried to do define a custom partition table but still same errors.

Comment: Are you rebuilding an existing server, or is this a pristine new virtual disk?

Comment: @Abhinav You may also want to modify your clearpart to:
`clearpart --all --initlabel`

Comment: Its a new server disk mean I am creating the stuff from scratch. I will add the configs for the reference.

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 3):

I found a potential problem:

```
      "iso_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso",
```

The CentOS "minimal" disk is customized and may do unexpected things, as it was intended and customized only to install a single set of packages. It should not be used with a kickstart installation; use the netinstall or DVD images instead.

Comment: Oh, I use the minimal ISO all the time for kickstart installs. It's never been an issue. I repeated the test below with the minimal ISO instead of the net install ISO with no change in outcome.

Comment: You're a braver man than I am, then. Knowing how they built the minimal image, I wouldn't use it for anything but pets.

Comment: This is an example as I can't put the actual image name in the config. We have our own custom spin for the application which is based on CentOS 6.4. So the actual errors is being reported through those disk installation. One more thing with CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso I am not facing any issue and the VM get created without any error.

Answer (score 2):

> But as I said the ISO is spin using CentOS 6.4 base and it should not impact the kickstart installation.

You need to verify this. Try with a standard ISO.

---

If it still gives the error, you told it to only clear `sda`:

```
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda
```

Change to:

```
clearpart --all --initlabel
```

and try again.

Comment: Already did that but still same error.

Comment: Did what? Both things? Or are you picking the one you already did and ignoring the other?

Comment: I have tried once `clearpart --all --initlabel` and when the problem still persist then I tried `clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda`. In both cases zerombr was put in the file. Also the kickstart file I am using is the one which anaconda installer create after manual install.

Comment: So the answer is no, you haven't tried both suggestions. OK.