# HP ML350 Gen8: error erasing disk cciss/c0d0 on PXE

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, pxe-boot, hp-smart-array

I Have a ML350 Gen8, that on first PXE Boot, will ask me whether I am sure I want to erase raid controller cciss/c0d0 giving me an option of Yes | No. This only happens when the disks are brand new out of the box.

Disk layout:

```
clearpart --all --drives=cciss/c0d0
part /boot --fstype ext3 --size=100 --ondisk=cciss/c0d0
part pv.2 --size=0 --grow --ondisk=cciss/c0d0
volgroup VolGroup00 --pesize=32768 pv.2
logvol swap --fstype swap --name=LogVol01 --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=512 --grow --maxsize=10
logvol / --fstype ext3 --name=LogVol00 --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=1024 --grow
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=cciss/c0d0 --append=""
```

Any Ideas would be great

Comment: Any danger of an actual question here?

Comment: What operating system are you trying to PXE boot? my solution for RHEL/CentOS is different than Ubuntu, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us what operating system you're wiring with? That's a big detail. I'll assume Red Hat or CentOS...

An HP Gen8 server under a modern OS will be using the [HPSA driver, not CCISS](https://serverfault.com/questions/272780/hp-smartarray-raid-controllers-linux-driver-differences-cciss-versus-hpsa). So your drives will be /dev/sdX... e.g. /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, etc. (maybe this isn't a Gen8 server)

Regardless, assuming RHEL or CentOS, you'll need the `zerombr` parameter in your kickstart to get around this issue.

From the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html):

> zerombr: 
>   If zerombr is specified any invalid partition
>   tables found on disks are initialized. This destroys all of the
>   contents of disks with invalid partition tables. This command is
>   required when performing an unattended installation on a system with
>   previously initialized disks.

Also see: [VMware ESXi CentOS 6.4 kickstart installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/604882/vmware-esxi-centos-6-4-kickstart-installion/604901#604901)